What are External Hardware Interventions?
The Intel Software Developoment Manual, vol. 3, lists sources of exceptions and interrupts in Table 6-2 “Priority Among Simultaneous Exceptions and Interrupts.”  In this table, priority 3 concerns “external hardware interventions” of which the following are listed:

FLUSH
STPCLK
SMI
INIT

Of these, only SMI (System Management Interrupt) rings a bell.  The others do not seem to be explained in the Intel SDM.  Could somebody could give me an explanation of what “external hardware intervention” is supposed to mean and what the four interventions listed are specifically?

See the last paragraph of section 6.3.1. There are also quite a few other mentions of INIT, STPCLK, and FLUSH in volume 3 of the SDM, so I'm not going to cite them all. (Note that STPCLK is generally spelled without an "O".)

In the first sentence, it should say "vol 3".

The CPU can be also controlled with specific-purpose pins. FLUSH# for example forces the flush of the TLBs. STPCLK# halt the CPU clock derived from the base clock as a power saving feature. INIT# is used to initialize the CPU after an halt. These generate async events that the CPU handles with more priority than other events. And all are "side" events w.r.t. to normal CPU operation (driven by instructions execution and hardware interrupts). You can find more information searching for pins with the same (or similar) names. I don't think there's a complete or updated list anywhere though.

@MargaretBloom If you could expand on that a little bit, that would suffice as an answer to my question.

Unfortunately that's all I know :/ I think "external hardware interventions" just mean those four events raised by the homonymous pins. Surely there are others but probably these are the only useful ones (for hardware and system designers) that Intel wants to publicly commit to.

@MargaretBloom: STPCLK# faintly rings a bell; I think my brother's laptop from a few years ago had some thermal throttling problems (after some physical damage that affected cooling), and I think my research found that STPCLK# could be asserted by the motherboard when things were too hot due for components around the CPU and/or GPU.  So at least one use-case for that pin is more about throttling for thermal / power limits than saving energy.
